# Create JAXB Object from large XML file

Tags: java, xml, object, jaxb

I'm looking for something to easily create an Object to access a large XML file.

The XML file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="WINDOWS-1252"?>
    <vzg:vzg erstellt_von="##" erstellt_am="###" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:vzg="###" xsi:schemaLocation="###">
      <auswahl sicht="B" basisfplp_id="0" basisve_id="0">
        <fplp vzg_id="0" periode="2012/2013"/>
        <version vzg_id="###" name="###"/>
        <strecke name="11801">
          <von baukms_nr="###" km="#.#"/>
          <bis baukms_nr="###" km="#.#"/>
        </strecke>
        <bst vzg_id="#" name="#" kurzbez="##" bez="####" kritart="#"/>
        <bst vzg_id="#" name="#" kurzbez="##" bez="####" kritart="#"/>
        <bst vzg_id="#" name="#" kurzbez="##" bez="####" kritart="#"/>
        <bst vzg_id="#" name="#" kurzbez="##" bez="####" kritart="#"/>
        <bst vzg_id="#" name="#" kurzbez="##" bez="####" kritart="#"/>
        ...
```

I want an Object to calculate with some of the XML Attributes.

Like:

List vzg_id=vzg.auswahl.bst;

int res=vzg_id.get(3) * vzg.auswahl.strecke.von.baukms_nr;

Since the XML has about 16000 Lines it's difficult to create a class for every XMLElement.

What I've done now:

MainClass

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

import java.io.File;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXB;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        VZG vzg = JAXB.unmarshal(new File("./XMLVZG.xml"), VZG.class);


        System.out.println(vzg.erstellt_am+ " "+vzg.erstellt_von+"\n"+vzg.aw.sicht);
    }
}
```

Class VZG

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class VZG
{
    @XmlElement(name="auswahl")
    AuswahlSicht aw;
    @XmlAttribute(name="erstellt_von")
    String erstellt_von;
    @XmlAttribute(name="erstellt_am")
    String erstellt_am;
    @XmlAttribute(name="xsi")
    String xmlns_xsi;   
}
```

Class Auswahl

```
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name="auswahl")
public class AuswahlSicht
{
    @XmlAttribute(name="basisfplp_id")
    int basisfplp_id;
    @XmlAttribute(name="basisve_id")
    int basisve_id;
    @XmlAttribute(name="sicht")
    String sicht;

}
```

So I'm now able to get the Attributes of the Root and the Cild, but I have still about 1000 childs with Attributes left and I'm looking for an automated way to parse the XML to get an object.
Simple Description:
XML File

```
<root>
 <child>
   <Subchild id="1"/>
    <subsubchild id=2/>
    <subsubchild id=33/>
 </child>
</root>
```

The object should then be like this:

List subsubchilds = root.child.subchild.subsubchild;
int id_one=subsubchilds.get(0);

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please include in your question, the exact description of the problem you are having.

Comment: As @Perception already mentioned, you should ask a question - what's your problem? Btw: Creating (JAXB based) object graphs out of a huge XML document is in most cases not a good idea as you need lots of memory (RAM) for this. You might have to think about a combination of streaming (SAX, StAX) and JAXB.

Comment: edited the Question to make it a bit more clear; the code I posted works smooth and the sorce xml file is well-formated. I'm open for other solutions, JAXB just seemed to work out well for me at first

Comment: Can you ask the people who created the data to provide you with an XSD? Then you'll be able to generate the classes.

Comment: @DaveRlz the original xsd isn't available. I created an xsd online which also looks fine, is that enough?

Comment: @PhilippAdam - the xsd you have generated may be enough, but it won't include the subtle relationships that may exist between data elements, you can't figure those out unless you know what the data actually represents which an online tool won't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is rarely a good idea to write JAXB classes by hand for existing XML. JDK has special command line tool to generate these classes for you (xjc) from XML schema. If schema is not available you could try to generate schema from XML (various tools can do that - for example XMLSpy) and then generate classes using xjc.

Comment: awesome...I ran the xjc with the online created xsd, fixed some minor stuff in the xsd and now i have my VZG object with the childs. is there now any way to bind the xsd with the xml again to get the data?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Perhaps take a look at Unmarshaller http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnbay.html

Comment: Yes, that did it. Basically these three lines helped me to bind the from the xsd created object back with the xml:    jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Vzg.class);
   Unmarshaller u = jc.createUnmarshaller();

   xml = (Vzg) u.unmarshal(new FileInputStream("###.xml"));